# Tag score doesn't seem to be updated this week

Tags: support, tag-score

It seems that my score for the tag angular2 wasn't updated this week (see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular2/topusers) whereas I contribute a lot...

Perhaps I'm wrong and I didn't see a reason for this but I would be interested in having your feedback on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Lots of complaints about it already this week.  They need to fix the bug, usually 6 to 8 days.

Comment: Thanks very much @HansPassant for your quick answer! So I will wait a bit ;-)